# tkinter Creating a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

there I am fairly new with python and object-oriented programming. Most of my experience is from C programming. However, for a personal project, I am using python and its Tkinter libraries to create a GUI on my computer. I was able to build the GUI and created different menu buttons for my project. However, for one of the menu buttons, I would like to open a new window with text and maybe images for the user.

Here is a snippet of the GUI
[image]

The location of my error is one of the classes that are in charge of creating the windows menu bars. With its public function named "read_me_exit"

Here is the snippet of my function and its properties

```py
def read_me_exit(self):

    win = tk()

    window_width = 400
    window_height = 200

    # get screen dimension
    screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = win.winfo_screenheight()

    # find the center point
    center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
    center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)

    # create the screen on window console
    win.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

    win.title('Read Me')
    win.resizable(False, False)
    win.iconbitmap('./msoe.ico')
```

This function gets called in my menubar command line as shown below:

```
class Window(tk.Frame):

    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        # field options

        # with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window()

    # Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):
        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object
        file = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Read Me", command=self.read_me_exit)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.user_exit)........
```

When trying to click the Read Me button on my file menubar I receive this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jurado-garciaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jurado-garciaj\Documents\EKG\GUI.py", line 196, in read_me_exit
    win = tk()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: use `tk.Tk()` instead of `tk()`

Comment: as the error suggests, `tk` is a module, not a function. Also, if you're creating a second window use `Toplevel`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged

Comment: Thank you that solving all my problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try instead using the `win = Toplevel()` command to create a new window instead of `win = tk()`

The `Toplevel()` acts almost exactly like the `Tk()` object, so you probably won't have to change any extra code.